# How to replace dynamic letters with regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like

```js
(Closedate<= '20210415') and (Type ='DynamicLettersLetterMix')
```

and I want to reduce it to just `(Closedate<= '20210415')` with a regular expression in JavaScript.

The `DynamicLettersLetterMix` is English based, it may contain numbers.
I know how to do the reduction if the `Type` is just a number (e.g.: `(Closedate<= '20210415') and (Type ='1')`):

```js
replace(/and\s*\(\s*Type\s*\=\'\d*\'\)/i,"")
```

I don't know how to do that with a `Type` that is a dynamic string.

How can I do that?

Comment: Thank Wiktor Stribiżew to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/\s*\band\s*\(\s*Type\s*='[^']*'\)/gi, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0tm19l/1/).

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `and` - a word `and`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `Type` - a word `Type`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `='` - a `='` string
- `[^']*` - ***any zero or more chars other than `'`, as many as possible***
- `'\)` - a `')` string.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "(Closedate<= '20210415') and (Type ='1 DynamicLettersLetterMix 2-4;')";
console.log(text.replace(/\s*\band\s*\(\s*Type\s*='[^']*'\)/gi, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just match the fragment you need:

```js
const input = "(Closedate<= '20210415') and (Type ='DynamicLettersLetterMix')";
const result = input.match("\\(Closedate\\s*[<>=]+\\s*'[0-9]+'\\)")[0];
console.log(result);
```

**[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/6Q3vuX/1)**